# Different files for different branches only locally

Tags: git

I have a git repository with two branches, eg master and customers
I have a database parameters file called eg db_config.php
This file must be different in both branches, but must never be 'pushed'.
Can I achieve this with git?

The only think that I can think of is instead of changing the branch with 'git checkout master' I can create a bash command, that changes the branch and renames/copies the db_config.php (the files should be in .gitignore).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to put your `db_config.php` in `.gitignore` and create an file called  `db_config.php.example`. Then when you deploy or send to your customer he/she would only need to copy the example to `db_config.php` file and insert correct credentials.

We often use similar behavior in our company where every developer has his own database settings.